# Access method directly from URL

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, url

I've watched video tutorial for a little MVC framework(if i can call it framework) - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/ 
,i download the source code and changed a little bit the files but I can't figure out how to call a specific method as CodeIgniter's form_open() and make a simple login system.Thanks in advance!
So ,how to send POST data from a form to the controller?
PS:I don't want to reinvent the wheel, just practicing

Comment: `Thanks in advance!` For what? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Yup,You are right ,sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also used this TinyMVC to learn MVC structure,
On your HMTL form:

```
<form method="POST" action="yoururl.com/index.php">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/> // name or ID.
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then in your controller or method just use

```
$username = $_POST('username');
```

You have to post to index.php, and it will go to your controller for you to pick up with there. You can also pick it up in a method using the same example.

Comment: But I'm not using CodeIgniter.

Comment: I have no idea how I made that mistake!, I've update the answer, its just a simple post to php.

Comment: No probs, I like this simple MVC stucture, its really easy to learn the separation of code and logic, although its very basic, it allows you to play around with the core and understand exactly how it works!